# Apache: forcing a 404 status code

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite

I am working with a tomcat application that I cannot modify, though I have full control over apache which is set up in front of it (with a reverse proxy).

The application will do a 302 redirect to `pagenotavailable.jsp` when it encounters a URL that's no longer valid (i.e. the ID no longer exists or is malformed).

I need to figure out a way to make these return a 404 so that these URLs drop out of the search engine indexes.

One possibility I came up with is to set up a mod_rewrite redirect from `pagenotavailable.jsp` to a page I made called `404.html` :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/pagenotavailable\.jsp /404.html [NC,R=404,L]
```

Or just this, since 404.html is already set up as ErrorDocument:

```
RewriteRule ^/pagenotavailable\.jsp$ - [R=404]
```

That is showing the *content* of my custom `404.html` page, but the URL does not update (it is still `pagenotavailable.jsp`) and the status code is still 302.

Any ideas why I don't get a 404, of any alternative approaches are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are responding with a `302`, then the client will always update its URL (e.g. in the URL bar) to show `.../pagenotavailable.html`. If you want that to go away, you'll have to redirect again to your preferred URL. The only other option would be to modify the application so it doesn't perform a redirect, but instead a "forward" which is handled entirely on the server-side. But you specifically mentioned that you can't modify the web app, soo...

I'd be very surprised if the status code were still `302`... when a client receives a `302` response, it should perform a GET to the `Location` provided in the `302` response header. If anything, I'd expect a 200 response with your `404.html` content if the response code wasn't being set to 404.

The `[R=xxx]` flag tells `mod_rewrite` to issue a redirect, which must be a `3xx` response code. You *can* use a 404, but you should be [aware of the caveats](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r). That page says what happens with the `Location` header (i.e. nothing) and it says that it will imply the `[L]` flag, but it doesn't say anything about what response code will actually be sent to the client.

What about using `RewriteRule` to rewrite the page to something that actually doesn't exist?

```
RewriteRule ^pagenotavailabe.jsp$ /does-not-exist.html
```

... then let your standard 404 handler handle the error (and return the contents of `404.html` plus the 404 protocol response).